# Dashing in Unity 2D Top-Down Projects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, 2d-games

So in 3D games I've used .AddForce(dashForce, ForceMode.Impulse) in order to calculate and execute the Dash-Function (and it worked like a charm). However, as I translated everything I knew into the 2D-world (so a Vector2 dashForce and using ForceMode2D) something isnt working correctly.

```
    public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header ("Running Values and bools")]
        private float vertical;
        private float horizontal;
        private float speed = 10f;
        private bool isFacingRight = true;

        [Header("Sprint")]
        private bool canSprint = true;
        public float sprintFactor = 5f;
        

        [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
        [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask hakenCheck;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;


        [Header("Dash Mechanic")]
        private bool canDash = true;
        private bool isDashing = false;
        public float DashCoolDown = 1f;
        public float DashDuration = 1f;
        private float DashFactorFront = 8f;
        
        [SerializeField] TrailRenderer tr;

        private void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
           
        }

        void Update()
        { 

            if (canDash && !isDashing && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Dash());
            }

        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical).normalized * speed;

               //sprinting - tr emitting
            if (canSprint == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical).normalized * speed * sprintFactor ;
                

            }

        }

        private IEnumerator Dash()
        {
            Debug.Log("Dash");
            canDash = false;
            isDashing = true;

            if (rb.velocity.x > rb.velocity.y || rb.velocity.x == rb.velocity.y)
            {
                Vector2 dashForce = rb.transform.right * DashFactorFront;
                rb.AddForce(dashForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashDuration);
                isDashing = false;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashCoolDown);
                canDash = true;
            }
            else if (rb.velocity.y > rb.velocity.x)
            {
                Vector2 dashForce = rb.transform.up * DashFactorFront;
                rb.AddForce(dashForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashDuration);
                isDashing = false;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashCoolDown);
                canDash = true;
            }
        }
     
        }
```

So what I know so far is that the coroutine gets executed (checked by testing with a Debug.Log message && also the cooldown I've implemented works). Hence, it seems like that the dash function / calculation has a problem / I had a wrong idea. I even tried out using different ForceModes, even though I recognized that there seems to be just "force" and "impulse" (none of those worked for me).

One thing I think is possible is that I have to use a empty as a child of the player inside the player and apply the force to the empty itself, however, this also havent worked out yet even though I tried it twice with different empty objects. So, in the end I stay clueless where this issue is based on. In the solution that I've provided I just went back to using the RigidBody as the source of the used axis (x,y) and applied the force to them.

Answer (score 0):

In `FixedUpdate` you are directly setting the `Rigidbody`'s velocity which undoes any force setting that you would be doing in `Dash`. By the looks of it you are trying to clamp the max velocity the `Rigidbody` can move, try this by calling:

```
rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, YOUR_MAX_SPEED);
```

instead of what you have:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical).normalized * speed;
```

As an aside you are also not using your fields `vertical`, `horizontal`, and `isFacingRight` at all. Currently you have:

```
float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
```

which will freeze the player in the air if they are falling or shoved by another `RigidBody`/`Collider2D`.

Hope this helps!